# Place div below element with fixed position and 100% height

Tags: html, css, fullscreen

I have two divs: `#lookbookHeader` and `#introContent`.  `#lookbookHeader` has a video in it with `position: fixed`, `height: 100%` and `height: auto`, which I followed from [this tutorial](http://demosthenes.info/blog/777/Create-Fullscreen-HTML5-Page-Background-Video). I would like `#introContent` to be below `#lookbookHeader`, regardless of the height, as you see on [this page](http://mainequarterly.com/beer/).  I am trying to create a page where the video is full viewport when the page loads, and you can scroll down to see additional content below.

I have tried every combination of positioning, floating and display on these two elements to try to get this to work and I just can't get it! Currently `#lookbookHeader` has no styles because it doesn't seem to matter what I apply to it, as the video styles override it when I apply position fixed. If I don't have fixed on the video, then it doesn't scale or size correctly with width/height. What am I missing?

I know I can use jQuery or JavaScript to get the height of `#lookbookHeader` when the page loads but wondering if there is a way to do this with CSS only.  You can see the page [here](http://lcoawebservices.com/dev/videobgTest.html).

I have checked other posts on SO, [such as this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16733641/positioning-a-wrapper-div-underneath-a-fixed-navigation-bar), but all seem to reference a fixed element with a set height which is not the case here.

**HTML**

```
            <div id="lookbookHeader">
                <video autoplay poster="http://lcoawebservices.com/assets/lp_stainless_SliderStop_5.jpg" id="bgvid">
                    <source src="http://lcoawebservices.com/assets/lp_stainless_Transition_5.webm" type="video/webm">
                    <source src="http://lcoawebservices.com/assets/lp_stainless_Transition_5.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                </video>
                <div id="headerContentContainer">
                    <h1>Lookbook: Spring 2015</h1>
                    <div class="initial-arrow-small"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="introContent">
            <h2>Bienvenue</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
            <div class="block red">one</div>    
            <div class="block blue">two</div>   
            <div class="block yellow">three</div>   
            <div class="block green">four</div> 
        </div>
```

**CSS**

```
    #introContent {
      max-width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      background-color: #fff;
    }
    #lookbookHeader video#bgvid {
      position: fixed;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      min-width: 100%;
      min-height: 100%;
      width: auto;
      height: auto;
      z-index: -100;
      background: url(http://lcoawebservices.com/assets/lp_stainless_SliderStop_5.jpg) no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
      display: block;
    }
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with CSS, as far as I can tell.  When I expand your content to make the page scrollable, it acts the same way your example website does.  The video is playing in the background, and scrolling only puts content on top of the video.  Check this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ek13geka/

Comment: I should have been more clear - when the page loads initially, i want all the content that is currently on top of the video, to be below it, except the Lookbook 2015 copy and the arrow. I am trying to do what is on the maine beer website linked above; the Synoposis content is below the video when the page loads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a top  `margin` to accomplish this. First you need to include `html` on the `body` styles:

```
html,body { //add html
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Then add `height:100%` to `.container` (for it's children). Then you can set the height and margin on `.introContent`. Also you have floated elements inside `.introContent` that you're not clearing. You can correct that by adding `overflow: hidden`:

```
#introContent {
  min-height: 100%; //add min-height
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: red; //changed so you can see the container better
  overflow: hidden; //add to clear floats
  margin: 50% 0 0; //add margin from top
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/3vv4t75s/)

## **UPDATE**

I have a better solution. Sometimes you just overthink things. Just simply add a blank `div` above the content like so:

```
<div class="spacer"></div>
<div id="introContent">
   ....
```

and set it to:

```
.spacer{
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
}
```

That will take up the height of the screen and bump your content down below

## [**BETTER FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/3vv4t75s/1/)

Comment: Thank you! Both solutions worked. I really appreciate the help and explanation.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to help. Go with the second one, it's going to be more reliable