# Positioning div relative (absolute) to a fixed navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a `fixed` navbar at the top of my page, and want to position an element below it, relative to how big the navbar is. When resizing the browser window, my navbar will jump into 2 or 3 lines from one, and I want my div (`.articles-showcase`) to move accordingly.

I tried achieving this by nesting my div inside the navbar container and using `position: absolute;`, `top: 0;`, but this just always positions my div at the top of the page.

Is there a way to do this using css, or should I look for a javascript solution?

I am currently using bootstrap and angular JS and wouldn't like to add jQuery to my project if not necessary.

Here's my html:

```
<div class="header" ng-controller="NavbarController">
  <ul>
    <li ng-class="{ active: isActive('/PTC-Testers') }"><a href="#/PTC-Testers">PTC-Testers</a></li><li ng-class="{ active: isActive('/articles') }"><a href="#/articles">articles</a></li><li ng-class="{ active: isActive('/sites') }"><a href="#/sites">PTC sites</a></li><li ng-class="{ active: isActive('/account_reviews') }"><a href="#/account_reviews">account reviews</a></li><li ng-class="{ active: isActive('/forum') }"><a href="#/forum">forum</a></li><li ng-class="{ active: isActive('/contact') }"><a href="#/contact">contact us</a></li><li ng-class="{ active: isActive('/login') }"><a href="#/login">login</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="articles-showcase">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
      <p>featured</p>
      <h1>What I learned while cooking</h1>
      <h3>author | posted </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
      <p>most read</p>
      <h1>My favorite things about dogs</h1>
      <h3>author | posted </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
      <p>highest rating</p>
      <h1>It's finally friday people!</h1>
      <h3>author | posted </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
      <p>featured track</p>
      <h1>starting your own adventure</h1>
      <h3>author | posted </h3>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

the relevant part of my CSS:

```
.header {
  background-color: red;
  color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 0.3em solid cyan;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 100%;
}
.header ul {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.header ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.header ul li a {
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 1em;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
}
.header ul li:hover {
  background-color: #ff6666;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.header ul .active {
  background-color: cyan;
}

.articles-showcase {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 11;
  border-bottom: 0.2em solid cyan;
  padding: 0.5em;
  width: 100%;
}
.articles-showcase div {
  text-align: center;
}
.articles-showcase div h1, .articles-showcase div h3, .articles-showcase div p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0.3em;
  color: #660000;
}
.articles-showcase div p {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  color: red;
}
.articles-showcase div h1 {
  font-size: 1.7em;
}
.articles-showcase div h3 {
  font-size: 1.4em;
}
```

Comment: Unless you have a Sass->CSS compilation issue, ONLY post the compiled CSS.

Comment: I use bootstrap along with ionicons, reset.css and compass. I am also importing all of my scss files into a single large file, before minimizing and compiling it into css. This is why the question is not tagged with CSS :)

Comment: And?  This is not a Sass problem, either.  You're supposed to provide the *smallest* amount of code necessary to reproduce the problem.  You've failed to do that (you don't need Sass to reproduce the problem).

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16733641/positioning-a-wrapper-div-underneath-a-fixed-navigation-bar

Comment: actually, since sass uses nesting I have provided the smallest amount of code necessary to reproduce the problem. The compiled css is longer, and harder to read.

Comment: Right, and I suppose you're going to tell me that all of those background color/color/font declarations are necessary to reproduce the problem, too?  Seriously, do *not* post Sass code unless Sass is part of the problem.

Comment: and no this is not a duplicate of the post you linked either. I'm not looking on how to position the div correctly. I'm looking into how to position it relatively to the height of my navbar (when for instance it changes when the user changes his phone orientation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the anwser from @Milos Miskone Sretin I came up with this crude jQuery solution:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
        $('.articles-showcase').css('top', $('.header ul').outerHeight());
    });
```

I still need to test this in different browsers and on mobile devices but for now, it seems to do the trick.

If anyone can come up with a css alternative to do this (maybe something including bootstrap classes that I do not know about), please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put div below fixed element you can do it by setting its top margin to height of navbar.

But, in your case, because you don't have fixed height it is not that simple. You need to use javascript to achieve this.

The simplest way is to use jQuery, if I am right, you already have it loaded since you are using bootstrap. Try in this way:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.articles-showcase').css('top', $('.header').outerHeight());
});
```

Also, I am not completely clear. Is both .articles-showcase and ul under header div. If you want to put .articles-showcase under ul do it like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.articles-showcase').css('top', $('.header ul').outerHeight());
});
```

You can do it without jQuery but using jQuery is an easiest way.
Hope this can help you.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it will only set the css top once. I guess I should try implementing it with the angular watcher directive?

Comment: This one is for document load, I am not quite familiar with Angular but you can implement in watch directive so it can triger the script everytime you need it.