# Adding new div shifts down my header

Tags: html

I am trying to add a text field under my blue header. I added a div and a `<p>` but all it does is shift down my header with a small space above.

How can I fix this?

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KXqGyp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already stated, you can remove the position. Alternatively, add a `padding-top` value to class `bio` in your CSS and set it to be at least equal to the height of your header (75px seemed fine).

The problem is that `position: fixed;` causes the header element to not take up space, where it normally would, so you need to create a buffer of whitespace above your first element in order to take up the space your header originally would have.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `position` CSS attribute from the `header` style.

Answer (score 0):

You can also change the `position` attribute for the header class to `position: static;`.

`static` is the default value, so just deleting the attribute makes it.

Answer (score 0):

Your positioning is the problem. You're setting a fixed position but not setting where that positioning is:

```
header {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    background: #4168a8;
    top: 0; /* specifying where you want to place the fixed item */
}
```

Once you do that you'll see that your content is now fixed to the top, but the divs are now below your fixed item. You'll need to set the top margin for whatever item you want under it to be greater than the height of your navbar in order for it to show up correctly.

Here's a related SO article: [Positioning a "wrapper" div underneath a fixed navigation bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16733641/positioning-a-wrapper-div-underneath-a-fixed-navigation-bar)